# Office 365 on iPad - SP.SOD.executeFunc not executing function

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365

I've written a function which is loading correctly (see the hokey alert at the top) which goes on to call SP.SOD.executeFunc to check if the device is an ipad then call SetFullScreenMode(true);

```
window.onload = function () {

alert('has loaded');
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', goToFullScreen);

function goToFullScreen() {
    alert('never gets called on an iPad'); // doesn't matter if isiPad is correct, this should at least happen
    var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1;
    if(isiPad) {
        SetFullScreenMode(true);
    }
}
};
```

It works just fine in Chrome and IE8 but doesn't work in iPad so executeFunc has any specific browser requirements. The "has loaded" message appears but nothing else executes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem with the script not executing was my fault, I needed to prompt the script to notify pending functions. Not clear why this doesn't work on the iPad specifically, but there you go.

For info, the script that works is;

```
window.onload = function () {


SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(goToFullScreen, 'sp.js');
function goToFullScreen() {

    var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1;
    if(isiPad) {
        SetFullScreenMode(true);
    }
}
SP.SOD.notifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("sp.js");
};
```